# React + springboot csrf

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf, csrf

i've a react application inside a springboot project, the react application use rest calls for get/set stuff. Actually i've disabled csrf inside the configure adapter `.csrf().disable()` but i'd like to menage this.
How can i handle csrf token between react and springboot?

I think that i should pass the token through my axios call, but how i get it?

Thanks

Comment: There is a good example which you can checkout https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to save `CSRF-TOKEN` to cookie and send it back with the request header.

SecurityConfig class.

Enable csrftokenrepsitory

```
         .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).addFilterAfter(new XSSFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

Add csrfTokenRepository

```
       private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName(X_CSRF_TOKEN);
    return repository;
}
```

In react, you can access token from the cookie.

```
    csrfToken=  cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
```

Send it as follows in the header.

```
     headers: {
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.csrfToken,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
```

https://github.com/supun/okta-spring-boot-react-crud-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/okta/developer/jugtours/config/SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: What is the part that actually saves the `csrf` token to a cookie? Does Spring Security manage this process? or should I save the token manually from the front-end layer?

Comment: @wonsuc yes. it is handled via spring security. no need to save it in the front end.

Answer (score 12):

The answer above I think it used an old spring security version. There's an easy way. For springboot backend, you can just do

```
.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

And for in react, you can do the way in that answer but don't forgot using `<CookiesProvider>` to wrap up what you return

Or you can just get the token from document.cookie. There should be a pair starting with XSRF-TOKEN=

And csrf should not be applied to GET method.

Comment: @wonsuc I'm not sure but I'm using org.springframework.security 5.1.5