# How to get csfr token if login page is disable

Tags: spring, spring-security

for example a simple spring configuration

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/create").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin();
```

with csfr enabled, the request for "/create" endpoint will be redirected to login page, where I can find _csfr value, then I can make another post request with a new header "X-CSRF-Token", and finally request will be served.
But what if login page is disable? :

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/create").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        //.and().formLogin();
```

server will return 403 forbiden, there will be no html page to parse, how can I get csfr value in this case?

Comment: What kind of application is making the POST request? There are various build-in ways to include the CSRF token when using Thymeleaf or Angular, for example

Comment: i use postman to test EP

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014494/11430047) shows one way of receiving the token as a cookie. I suggest also taking a look at the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf) to learn more about CSRF and see which approach is best for your scenario.